# Как выровнять элемент, чтобы не появлялась полоса прокрутки?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верстаю шапку сайта. Когда надпись `KOT_Mapku3` имеет свойство `position: absolute`, а `header` (блок в котором она содержится `position: relative`), то при отступе проблем нет, т.к. полоса прокрутки(горизонтальная не появляется).

Но тогда желтый блок не воспринимает надпись и оказывается под ней.

`margin: 0 auto` для зеленого блока почему-то не работает.
http://embed.plnkr.co/4YydmUqTgL3aimNApu7i/
https://codepen.io/KOT_Mapku3/pen/oeWGdW

Comment: Добавьте код , JSFDD или аналоги

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK вроде, ссылка рабочая, проверьте

Comment: Чорт, прочитал кот_мапку три

Comment: @Duoxx ох уж этот злой транслит)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе .name-of-blog вообще уберите display: inline-block, а в .name-of-blog h1 добавьте ширину, к примеру, 250px (width: 250px). После этого надпись КОТ МАРКИЗ выравнивается по центру. Если нужно, чтобы .menu и .icons были по центру, то для них display: block и margin: 0 auto. Position вообще считаю нецелесообразным здесь для выравнивания по центру.